# How does a firebase project need to be configured to get Google login working from an Expo Snack?

Tags: firebase, expo

I'm trying to get Google Login working with Firebase from an Expo snack. I can login with Google and get the idToken and accessToken, but when I try to signInWithCredential to Firebase, I get a message that "the Google id_token is not allowed to be used with this application.". I feel like I'm missing some Firebase configuration step that I couldn't find in any of the Expo Firebase tutorials.

What step might be missing in my Firebase configuration or this Expo snack?   https://snack.expo.io/HJWiiNRtW

Comment: did you just log-in using Google-login and called firebase function which was supposedly for firebase auth?

Comment: Yes. I am doing just what is shown in the snack link.

Comment: After successfully logging in to Google, I'm attempting to login in to the Firebase project. I haven't found a good example of how to login to a Firebase project using Google from Expo.

Comment: i think the error should already give you an idea that this is not meant to be. I haven't tried Expo Snack, but if you're going to use firebase methods, use firebase auth not google sign-in.

Comment: Based on all the examples that I've seen, Firebase auth does not seem to work from React Native. So any implementation showing how to do Firebase login from React Native would answer my question.

Comment: How bout this Youtube tutorial: [React Native - Firebase Authentication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NI56LkqrB7A) ? A simple Googling returns tutorials related to firebase auth with react native. But try that first.

Comment: Correct, but that is another tutorial on how to get Facebook rather than Google login working. The Expo tutorial does something similar. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-firebase.html#content  What is difficult to find is the code to get Firebase Google login working from React Native.

Answer (score 0):

Older post, but for posterity sake:

Your setup on the Expo snack looks fine.  The problem you are having is a result of a mismatch between the client ID in the google developer console and firebase google Web SDK settings.

From google developer console, in your app, this will be the **Client ID for Web application**

`603386649315-vp4revvrcgrcjme51ebuhbkbspl048l9.apps.googleusercontent.com`
there will also be a client secret in there too.

In the firebase console for your app, in the authentication section, under google, click on **Web SDK Configuration**
and put the above noted project number (Web client ID) and client secret, and put these in their respective spots.

You will see that the project # being referenced in the error "873097287154..." will already be in the Web Client ID text box which is what you will replace with the client ID from google as noted above.